# How can I make a URL on one domain "front" content from another domain?

Tags: seo, domains, redirects, subdomain, reverse-proxy

Let's say I have `name.example.com` and `example.com` set up using different CMS's

I would like `name.example.com/supercool-landing-page` to resolve as `(www.)example.com`

In other words, when you visit `(www.)example.com`, what you are really seeing is `name.domain.com/supercool-landing-page`.  However, it is important that the url stays as `(www.)example.com`, for SEO reasons (for on-page content and user experience).

My reason for wanting to do this is because the CMS that's powering `example.com` is not good for creating landing pages with, whereas `name.example.com` is running Wordpress, which is perfect for creating landing pages with.

Answer (score 5):

This type of indirection is called a **reverse proxy** setup.

To reverse proxy in **Apache2**, use the `ProxyPass` directive in your config for `www.example.com`:

```
ProxyPass "/"  "http://name.example.com/supercool-landing-page"
```

To reverse proxy in **nginx**, use the `proxy_pass` directive in your config for `www.example.com`:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://name.example.com/supercool-landing-page;
}
```

Those aren't complete configurations, you also need to proxy_pass all the resources (images, js, css) that are used by the WordPress page. But it should help get you started.

The final piece of the puzzle is to make sure your apex domain `(example.com)` is redirecting to `www.example.com`. This is good practice for any website.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a shot! In the meantime, quick question: is the *opposite* of the apex domain (example.com) redirecting to www.example.com, alright or should it always end up as www.example.com?  (in my case www.example.com redirects to example.com)  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Gottano The short answer is that it's fine to host on either *apex* or *www*. The long answer is that there are some very subtle, usually but not always negligible disadvantages to hosting on the *apex* domain, so I am of the opinion that given a choice, [everyone should be using www](https://www.yes-www.org/why-use-www/). Whichever one you choose, redirect the other one to it.

Comment: OK so I am with Cloudways and they told me they don't allow "customization of their stack", so they do not make "httpd.conf" available. What other files should I look to modify instead? Sorry for asking but they aren't being proactive and feel I need to ask them directly if "this" and "that" is possible.

Comment: I can see I have the following files in /config (but they cant be editted):   custom-recv.vcl, custom-resp.vcl, server.apache and server.nginx

Comment: @Gottano From a quick Google search, I don't see any definitive evidence that Cloudways supports reverse proxying. Have you asked them [specifically about whether they support reverse proxying, rather than about which config files are editable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/299116)? They might have a different way they do it.

Comment: Well, the client support person told me it could be done via ".htaccess and the help of a developer" so that's why Im at loss, really.

Comment: @Gottano I found a bit more context [on this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/895282/configuring-reverse-proxy-with-mod-proxy-rules-using-only-htaccess-file), but I'm nearing the edge of my experience. A comment at that link suggests using `RewriteRule` with the `P` flag. Support should have at least told you what directive to use or given an example!

Comment: I know, right?  Well, many thanks for your help so far!